# How can I download a file from a URL with a varying file extension on windows with native scripting?

Tags: windows, script, download

I want to download a file from a specific url, the file will change extension, but not name, and I want the same download command to be able to download the file no matter what the file extension is.

I have tried wget in powershell, ex:

```
wget example.com/test/file
```

This gets the file, but only doesn't download it to a file. I can use this:

```
wget example.com/test/file -OutFile file
```

But this doesn't add the file extension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the file extension one of a set of known extensions?  Does the web server have directory browsing enabled so you can see the latest filename?

Comment: Directory browsing is enabled, and it would be ideal to have it work with any extension, but .exe, .bat, and .png are the set that I would like to at least have.

Comment: Well you could use this approach: https://pastebin.com/feRb67eD it tries each of the array of extensions in turn, so you could add to that list.